# Configuring jboss7 ajp connector timeout

Tags: jboss7.x

I am setting up Jboss7 to work with apache http using ajp.
My server.xml has the following entry to open ajp port

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" native="false" default-virtual-server="default-host">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" port="8080"/>
    <connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" port=8009 enabled="true" />
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

However when i try adding connectionTimeOut="10000" after port definition, I get the following error in boot.log

> Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException:
>   JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration     at
>
> org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:125)
>   [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     at
>
> org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:187)
>   [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:261)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155)
>   [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     ... 1 more Caused
>   by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[411,13] Message: JBAS014788: Unexpected attribute
>   'connectionTimeout' encountered   at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.unexpectedAttribute(ParseUtils.java:104)
>   [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.WebSubsystemParser.parseConnector(WebSubsystemParser.java:831)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.WebSubsystemParser.readElement(WebSubsystemParser.java:389)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.WebSubsystemParser.readElement(WebSubsystemParser.java:60)
>     at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:893)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:329)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:126)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:117)
>   [jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]     ... 4 more
>
> ```
>     15:47:20,423 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" stopped in 29ms
> ```

My question is how do we configure timeout in jboss7.
I folllowed http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/config/ajp.html and I could not make out the configuration required in server.xml .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found from jboss experts

https://community.jboss.org/message/779774?_sscc=t